# putting fields labels in django table in first row

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to:

1. print the label in the first row
2. set with of each field to 45px
3. put the first column where C will enumerate 1,2,3,... according to the rows.

it should be something like this:

| V | x1 | x2 | direct | RHS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | field | field | field | field |
| C2 | field | field | field | field |
| C3 | field | field | field | field |

in the body of page.html:

```
<table>
    {% for form in formset  %}
        <tr> {{ form.label }}
            {% for item in form %}
                <td style="width:10px; text-align: center">{{ item }}</td>
                    {% if not item.label_tag = 'direction' %}
                        ...do something...
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {%  endfor %}
</table>
```

in forms.py:

```
class linprog_vars(forms.Form):
    x1 = forms.FloatField(label='x1')
    x2 = forms.FloatField(label='x2')
    direct = forms.CharField(label='direct')
    rhs = forms.FloatField(label='rhs')
```

En views.py

```
def linprog(request):
    extra_lines = 3
    formset = formset_factory(linprog_vars, extra=extra_lines)
    context = {'formset': formset}
    return render(request, 'linprog/linprog.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, I think (untested). A formset is a list of similar forms, so the labels for all of them will normally be the same. So just iterate over the fields in the first one `formset.0` picking out the field labels.

```
<table> 
  <thead>
  <tr>
    {% for field in formset.0 %} 
      <th style="..."> {{ field.label }} </th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  </thead>
  ...etc as in question
```